# Why fedora dnf allways retrying to install failed packages first?

Tags: linux, fedora

When I want to install new packages by using `dnf` in `fedora 36`. it always trying to install previous failed packages first like this:

For example:

```
[user@fedora ~]$  sudo dnf install -y unrar
AnyDesk Fedora - stable                         0.0  B/s |   0  B     01:19
```

> Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'anydesk':
>
> - Curl error (56): Failure when receiving data from the peer for http://rpm.anydesk.com/fedora/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Recv failure: Connection reset by peer]
>
> Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'anydesk': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried

How to disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not try to install a package. It tries to update a Repo. You must disable the AnyDesk Repo:

```
sudo dnf config-manager --set-disabled <repo>
```

Another way would be to mv the repo file:

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
mv <repo> <repo>.disabled
```

Where  ist the filename of the repo. Find it out with `ls`.